# Want to create a place where people can admin there clients thru whatsapp, like whaticket but with oficial api, am I in the right place with Twilio?

Tags: twilio

I intent to create a website for my clients, called eg: xxxx.com where they will login into that website, and will be able to read a whatsapp QRCODE and connect to there whatsapps numbers and administrate there clients thru my website, like answer clients, transfer to other users from these user account and so on. Each client should be able to have multiple numbers connected within there account.

So let's say, client Joe purshases plan gold in my website, he will get a login and password, after that, Joe will log into xxxx.com and in section 'CONNECTION' he will be able to read a QRCODE and  'connect' his whatsapp numbers . Yes, he should be able to connect many numbers if he wishes to ! That way he will have many 'Active Connections'.
Can I do that using Twilio ?
Will he need to verify every single number on facebook platform ? Or that was only for me, the owner of twilio`s account ?

Please, make an easy answer so I can understand it, I'm new to all these , show me the path, I`ll use PHP/websockets along my journey !! Is these 100% possible ?

Thank you very much !!

Comment: This is way too broad to be asked here in this way. We are not here to create something akin to a full-on tutorial for you, just because you are "new" to a subject matter.

Answer (score 0):

Your project sounds exciting and complex. However, I'm not sure the WhatsApp API can help you to solve that problem (if I understand it right).

WhatsApp Business API is designed to allow medium and large businesses to communicate with their customers at a larger scale. For this model, each number would be treated as a unique business with its own WhatsApp Business Profile.

However, WhatsApp doesn't allow the same phone number to be used with both the API and the WhatsApp phone app. This is a critical restriction set by WhatsApp itself, which is essential to keep in mind while designing your project.

For using WhatsApp Business API with Twilio or any other provider, each number must be separately verified and approved by Facebook, regardless of who owns the Twilio account. This is because each number is considered as a unique business identity.

So, to answer your question directly, while you can certainly build a website to manage multiple numbers, the restriction of not being able to use a number simultaneously with the API and a personal WhatsApp account, **will make it impossible to implement this scenario**.

Lastly, since you have mentioned that you're new to this, I recommend you to study the [WhatsApp Business Platform documentation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/whatsapp) thoroughly. It will be helpful to fully understand its capabilities and restrictions, which in turn will help you plan your project more effectively.